# Dynamic horizontal sizing of jscrollpane container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, vertical-scrolling, dynamic-resizing

I have a **centered liquid** layout that has a help/intro section at the top of each page.  I use jQuery to hide/re-show the help content based on the user's needs.  Under this, I have the rest of the page content, which uses jScrollPane to display overflow content.

When the help content is hidden, I need the jspContainer to resize to fill the area where the help content was (not just slide up, since this happens already).  In other words, I need to fill the entire  with the page's content, and have jScrollPane resize the  along with the jsp scroll bars, etc.

I am using jQuery to dynamically re-draw the page anytime the onResize event is triggered, so I presume that I should insert the code in this event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery to make the div 100% width? Some example code would go a long way

```
$('#itemId').css({
    'width' : '100%'
});
```

Comment: It's not the width (horizontal) dimension that needs to flow, its the height (vertical) dimension that needs to increase/decrease as teh content above it is shown/hidden.  I have my width set to 100% in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this example shows exactly what you are trying to do:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_width.html